# Traverson Library to consume a RESTful webservice throws error with JSONPath

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-boot

I'm currently trying to get the **traverson** [library](https://github.com/basti1302/traverson) to fetch some information from an REST interface provided by SpringBoot.

My goal for now would be to get **traverson** to follow the path to
http ://localhost/users and fetch the information by using this code

```
traverson.from('http://localhost:8090')
    .json()
    .follow('$._links.user')
    .getResource(function(err, resource){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;    
        }
        console.log(resource);        
    });
```

The json structure which is returned upon calling the endpoint looks like this:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "ressource" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8090/ressource{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "user" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8090/user{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "alert" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8090/alert{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this results in an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.step.url.search is not a function
```

However if I just fetch the endpoint without the JSONPath Syntax it provides me the mentioned structure.
It will produce a more sensible error when I mess up the JSONPath Expression:

```
[Error: JSONPath expression $.links.user returned no match in document:
{"_links":{"ressource":{"href":"http://localhost:8090/ressource{?page,size,sort}
","templated":true},"user":{"href":"http://localhost:8090/user{?page,size,sort}"
,"templated":true},"alert":{"href":"http://localhost:8090/alert{?page,size,sort}
","templated":true}}]
```

Might be that I'm missing something super obvious which would be nice...

At least thanks for reading this far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom it might concern,
After some trial and error it turns you have to be very careful about the JSON Path expression you provide.

```
traverson.from('http://localhost:8090')
        .json()
        .follow('$._links.user.href')
        .getResource(function(err, resource){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return;    
            }
            console.log(resource);        
        });
```

This will work while this:

```
traverson.from('http://localhost:8090')
        .json()
        .follow('$._links.user')
        .getResource(function(err, resource){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return;    
            }
            console.log(resource);        
        });
```

will not.
The reason seems to be that $._links.user points to an object not an object attribute (see the endpoint structure above). This causes the evaluating function within the traverson library to cause a somewhat unintelligible error.

Let's hope that someone might make use of this information and doesn't spend hour brooding over this.

EDIT 1: After filling an issue with the library’s owner, this issue should now longer occur